# Как написать универсальное регулярное выражение для поиска всех картинок на странице?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть такие строки:

```
<img src="images/certificate_thumbnail.jpg" alt="Сертификат">
<div class="certificate_item" data-image="images/certificate.jpg">
<div class="button" data-button="images/button.jpg">
background: url(../images/logo.png) left bottom no-repeat;
```

Как написать регулярное выражение, которое во всех случаях бы определяло путь до изображения?

И посоветуйте толковую литературу по регуляркам. Сколько не читал, не могу вникнуть.

Comment: Парсить `HTML` с помощью `RegEx` плохая практика ([мем](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/11558617)). Так ли Вам это нужно?

Comment: Если хотите делать велик, то - https://regex101.com/r/0Jvmns/1 . Но это плохая практика, используйте библиотеку `DOM`.

Comment: Читайте "Регулярные выражения", Джеффри Фридл.

Answer (score 1):

Хочу подробнее описать свое видение на счет решения этой задачи, я конечно, могу ошибаться, то я предпочел бы сделать именно так. 
 Первое, что приходит в голову, это разобрать страницу с помощью библиотеки [`DOM`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php). Второе - регулярные выражения.

### Решение с помощью `DOM`:

<sup>**Исключительно HTML**! Никакого отношения к CSS тут нет.</sup>

Предположим, у нас имеется следующий код:

```
$code = <<<HTML
    <img src="images/certificate_thumbnail.jpg" alt="Сертификат">
    <div class="certificate_item" data-image="images/certificate.jpg">
    <div class="button" data-button="images/button.jpg">
HTML;
```

Мы юзаем библиотеку и начинаем его парсить:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($code);
```

Далее я бы сделал следующий ассоциативный массив, ключами которого будут являться необходимые теги, в которых будет осуществлен поиск (`*` - значит пройтись по каждому тегу, при необходимости, как в вопросе, можно изменить на `div`), а значения необходимые атрибуты, в которых должен был произведен поиск.

```
$basic = [
    '*' => ['data-image', 'data-button'],
    'img' => ['src']
];
```

И самое важное, и не очень красивое, это тройной цикл прохода по тегам и их атрибутам. Также сюда я добавил небольшую проверку на расширение изображений.

```
foreach ($basic as $key => $value)
    foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName($key) as $k)
        foreach ($value as $j) 
            if (preg_match('/\.(?:jpe?g|svg|png|gif)$/', $k->getAttribute($j)))
                $result[] = $k->getAttribute($j);
```

Далее данные, если таковые найдены - заносятся в массив `$result`. Затем мы его фильтруем от пустых строк, и выводим:

```
$result = array_values(array_filter($result));
print_r($result);

// Array ( [0] => images/certificate.jpg [1] => images/button.jpg ) and etc.
```

https://3v4l.org/f1sMO

### Решение с помощью регулярных выражений:

Данное решение является универсальным, как для HTML, так и для CSS. Но плохая практика.

Рассмотрим регулярное выражение:

```
'/(?:url|data-image|img.+?src|data-button)[=]?\(?(?!data)['"]?\K[^)'"]+/'
```

Пояснение:

- `(?:url|data-image|img.+?src|data-button)` незахватывающая маска для поиска атрибутов
- `[=]?` - знак `=`, который может не присутствовать
- `\(?` - экранирование скобки
- `(?!data)` - отрицательный lookahead для слова `data` (исходя из ваших предыдущих вопросов)
- `['"]?` - подмножество символов `'`, `"` - могут не быть.
- `\K` - отбрасывание всего, что было до
- `([^)'"]+)` - необходимый захват

https://regex101.com/r/0Jvmns/1